# Update database with another database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two databases(Say 'A' and 'B'). Many changes are used to done in 'A' database, but after certain time period, I need to make 'B' database too same as 'A'. Currently I am deleting and creating 'B' database, which seems the easiest to me. But, I'm curious is there any method so that I can just update 'B' from 'A'. Also, I think in case of large size of database, if I use delete and create method, it costs too much time to me. If there's any advice or solution, I feel highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for database replication.

[Hope this link would be useful.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms151799.aspx)

Comment: My both databases are in same computer.